# Problema al crear un tipo de dato struct con parámetros

Tags: c++

Tengo un struct que me representa un numero fraccionario y la funcion crear:

```
typedef struct{
    int num;
    int deno;
}Racional;

Racional* crear(int, int);
```

Quiero mostrar dos numeros fraccionarios en consola, al asignarle los respectivos valores con la función crear el segundo numero fraccionario toma otros valores.

```
int main(){
    Racional *a, *b;
    int num, deno;

    cout<<"Programa que realiza operaciones basicas con racionales"<<endl<<endl;

    cout<<"Ingrese el valor del numerador del racional 1: ";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"\nIngrese el valor denominador del racional 1: ";
    cin>>deno;
    a = crear(num, deno);
    cout<<"\nIngrese el valor del numerador del racional 2: ";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"\nIngrese el valor denominador del racional 2: ";
    cin>>deno;
    b = crear(num, deno);

    cout<<"El racional 1 es: "<<a->num<<"/"<<a->deno<<endl; 
    cout<<"El racional 2 es: "<<b->num<<"/"<<b->deno<<endl;
}

Racional* crear(int num, int deno){
    Racional *a = (Racional*)malloc(sizeof(Racional));

    a->num = num;
    a->deno = deno;

    return a;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En C++ no debes usar malloc, en vez de ello use new: `Racional *a = new Racional;`

Comment: Esos resultados de donde salen? porque en tu código no está la impresión de esas líneas que muestras.

Comment: @eyllanesc Ya he probado usan el "new" y obtengo el mismo resultado.

Comment: @SuperG280, ya he añadido la parte de la impresión pero no veo error alguno ahí.

Comment: ¿Qué  compilador estás usando?

Comment: Es imposible que el código que has puesto reproduzca el problema que comentas. O el código que usas para reproducir el problema no es exactamente el que has puesto aquí o, probablemente, tu compilador no esté funcionando correctamente

Comment: Para empezar, la salida de consola muestra el texto `Resultados` que no aparece en tu código... por favor, pon el código sin recortar

Comment: Acabo de probar el código y funciona perfecto, es muy raro que te de otro resultado, no tendrás por ahí algún otro código o declaración que este afectando al resultado final?

Comment: Pues siento decirte que tras tu actualización estamos en el mismo punto. Ya te lo han dicho en otros comentarios. Déjate de misterios y pon el código completo si quieres que alguien te conteste algo con sentido.

Answer (score 2):

> Tengo un struct que me representa un numero fraccionario y la funcion crear:
>
> ```
> typedef struct{
>     int num;
>     int deno;
> }Racional;
>
> Racional* crear(int, int);
> ```

Mal comienzo. Dado que has etiquetado la pregunta como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) y estás usando utilidades de dicho lenguaje (como los flujos de entrada/salida de datos desde consola `std::cin`/`std::cout`) haz que tu código se ajuste a dicho lenguaje y no a su predecesor [c](/questions/tagged/c):

En C++:

- Las estructuras son tipos de primer nivel, no necesitan una definición de tipo (`typedef`).
- Las estructuras pueden tener constructores, no necesitan una función de creación. Pero como todos los miembros son públicos (comportamiento por defecto de las estructuras) podemos usar la [inicialización de agregado](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).
- Se evita el uso innecesario de punteros en crudo.

Por lo tanto, tu estructura `Racional` podría tener este aspecto:

```
struct Racional {
    int num{};
    int deno{};
};
```

Las llaves al final de las variables miembro hacen que el valor se inicialice a cero. Para crear un `Racional` cualquiera de estas opciones es válida:

```
Racional mitad{1, 2};         // ½
auto tercio = Racional{1, 3}; // ⅓
```

Como ves, no hay necesidad de una función `crear` y tanto `mitad` como `tercio` son instancias, no punteros.

> Quiero mostrar dos numeros fraccionarios en consola.

En C++, la manera habitual de hacerlo es sobrecargando el operador de inyección en flujo de datos:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Racional &r) {
    return o << r.num << '/' << r.deno;
}
```

Con esta sobrecarga del operador, puedes mostrar un `Racional` directamente:

```
cout << "El racional 1 es: " << a << endl; 
cout << "El racional 2 es: " << b << endl;
```

Para leer desde consola, puedes sobrecargar el operador de extracción desde flujo de datos:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &i, Racional &r) {
    i >> r.num;
    i >> r.deno;
    return i;
}
```

Con estos cambios, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
int main()
{
    Racional a, b;

    std::cout << "Programa que realiza operaciones basicas con racionales\n\n";

    std::cout << "Ingrese el racional 1: ";
    std::cin >> a;

    std::cout << "\nIngrese el racional 2: ";
    std::cin >> b;

    std::cout
        << "El racional 1 es: " << a << '\n'
        << "El racional 2 es: " << b << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZE/b4MwEMVn/ClOqRSIRP9AN4LYOnSrOrMcxkKW4ExtszTqZ6c2EJpCJIY7@733uzO87x8bzsfxQRJvh1pALpWxWmBXMOaKgVv4RC4VYQsXFkiyQEN3@TnPdS1I@cZ9Tl5n2eKGo@qFRqt0nkebixi4InOTe9Qnn62FHTSBgjwH/eQovgifw7n3JMdZMHKLKYro/4WMdwAJRTEnn9dmjr2y5UTwi3UoKTox51pTMIbKrRlMHK4G6wc7fGjVaOwQvgYBDt3Kb4RpKm8TBio0kqPxS4NesoQpqaTDPu2dGi2MANGuWkgycMpFKMnPjXtnSfe86d57Z4e3WxoI40z@HKcfUFLIgmArS/9k1VXmg5eHfHEPOY4JS1nCXtkv)</kbd>.

---

Esto no soluciona tu problema, porque el código que has mostrado [no reproduce el problema que describes](https://tio.run/##rZI9b4NADIb3@xVWukCUqArdGsrWoVvVuYs5HHTS4aN3UKmp8tupCR8iaqIuRQJh4/fxax@6rrel1l13Z1jbtiBIjQuNJ6wypdpguATGikKNmiA0xV6p5qumgg4S@VY33wrkMtwAt9V@Dgpit1enN9TGMVqRTa9r0IL30SjZzOXxgJrqYI3wBNEsiyu01ukomCO5w5yPY2H3OtxmghPJ7EMyPVdSg5tz0lPTegYUc0r1rSs0HP3uvYF1vl/OtllStGubNF29eld6rBA@WhIyWnNEcDX5M4cC5BiMxiD1DH6EU1ilKXFhh@cl8YVLT4GALHyidV6a2r67IIsxmjiwe4TVYFEbzrJ57hH1zldg7CrDf6KGSc87lO0N5zWvIP67y03Lyf9ZTm5Zzq9aXrZ5Xk4OFISUpsP/I1/vh6DXjScEt8TJJM6X4vxCrE5dt1OJepD7Bw), deberías aportar un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de tu problema, no un código que no reproduzca el problema que dices tener; hasta entonces tendrás que conformarte con esta respuesta.

Sin embargo, el código mostrado no tiene el problema que describes y hace que tener problemas como el que describes sea muy difícil.

Comment: No veo cómo esto corrige el error que tiene.. introduce 2 y 3 e imprime 4 y 4 ... vale que el error no aparece en la pregunta... pero esta respuesta dificilmente va a solucionar el problema... otro tema aparte es que tengas o no razón (que va a ser que si) en las cosas que comentas... pero no solucionan el problema

Comment: No lo corrige. Su código no se comporta como dice que se comporta.

Comment: entonces no hay error... si no hay error hay que cerrar la pregunta... no responderla 

Comment: Tienes razón :O pero no podía dejar que un código tan malo quedase sin su contraparte corregida >_<

Comment: ya, eso también lo comparto